# Unable to access model data from inside called action after post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm having trouble accessing Model data in a .NET CORE web site I am putting together (my first attempts using CORE / MVC). I have a page of checkboxes and textboxes where a user can select certain criteria; a submit button should post this back to a controller action. I am having trouble accessing this data after post - I do not thing it's coming across at all.

This method is unable to see the criteria variable.

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToPageResult UpdateSpoiler(InputCriteria criteria)
{
  // Update both our criteria (from the form) and data selection (from the new criteria) and then redirect back to the index page
  _dataRepository.updateCriteria(criteria);
  _dataRepository.updateDataSelection();
  return RedirectToPage("Index");
}
```

The criteria I select never update and I don't ever see anything in this method. I am not even sure if it's being called properly.

Here is an excerpt of the relevant code from the view page:

```
@model SpoilerAnalysisViewModel;

<form asp-controller="SpoilerAnalysis" asp-action="UpdateSpoiler" method="post">
   <div style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px">
      <pre><label asp-for="@Model.criteria.White"></label><input asp-for="@Model.criteria.White" /
           <label asp-for="@Model.criteria.Blue"></label><input asp-for="@Model.criteria.Blue" />
      </pre>
   </div>
   <div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-route="@Model.criteria">Update Output</a>
   </div>
```

I am using standard routing for MVC, nothing custom. Can anyone suggest some options I can try?

Comment: Your post action is expecting a model "InputCriteria"  but your view is using a model of SpoilerAnalysisViewModel. Try updating your post action to use "SpoilerAnalysisViewModel" and see if you start getting data back.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried it both ways - SpoilerAnalysisViewModel contains an InputCriteria class (which is why I try to pass just @Model.criteria). I've tried both ways and neither work unfortunately. Any other thoughts? Thanks for reading!

Comment: The anchor link`<a>` is used for `GET` method not `POST` and it will never hit the post action.Do you mean the form has multiple inputs and you only would like to post part of data related to `criteria` data?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a SpoilerAnalysisViewModel model in your page but expecting a InputCriteria Model which is incorrect. You can use fiddler to see what object you are sending to the method.

You can change the method parameter and receive the SpoilerAnalysisViewModel, then in your code you can access the InputCriteria with:

> SpoilerAnalysisViewModel.InputCriteria

Answer (score 0):

Change you anchor link to submit button,I use below code and it works:

View:

```
<form asp-controller="SpoilerAnalysis" asp-action="UpdateSpoiler" method="post">
<div style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px">
    <pre>
        <label asp-for="@Model.criteria.White"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.criteria.White" />
        <label asp-for="@Model.criteria.Blue"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.criteria.Blue" />
  </pre>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Update Output"/>
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToPageResult UpdateSpoiler(SpoilerAnalysisViewModel model)
{
    var criteria = model.criteria;
    //...
}
```